# Return records from a table which have a match on all records of another table

Tags: sql, join

Having the following three tables in a DBMS:

```
Customer(Id, Name, City),
Product(Id, Name, Price),
Orders(Cust_Id, Prod_Id, Date)
```

What is the query which fetches the Customers (if any) who have ordered **all** Products?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select c.id
from customer c
inner join orders o on o.cust_id = c.id
inner join product p on p.id = o.prod_id
group by c.id
having count(distinct p.id) = (select count(id) from product)
```

Comment: Isn 't neccesary for the p.id to appear also in the "select" Statement? In other words, can we use in "having" whatever column we want?

Comment: you can use any column you want in the `having` clause as long as it is used in an aggregate function like `count` or `sum` and so on.